# AndEngine TXMLLoader null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, andengine, tmx

I am trying to load a tmx file in andengine. I have copied the example from AndEngine examples and created a new tmx file which i am loading. But I am getting NullPointerException on line tmxLoader.loadFromAsset("tmx/test.tmx"); . the test.tmx file just contain a single tile. It is giving the following error log:

```
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):
> TMXTiledMapExample.onCreateScene failed. @(Thread: 'GLThread 13')
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495): java.lang.NullPointerException
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLayer.addTileByGlobalTileID(TMXLayer.java:274)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLayer.initializeTMXTilesFromDataString(TMXLayer.java:247)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXParser.endElement(TMXParser.java:197)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.endElement(ExpatParser.java:158)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method) 08-29
> 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):  at
> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:518)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318) 08-29
> 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):  at
> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275) 08-29
> 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):  at
> org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLoader.load(TMXLoader.java:117) 08-29
> 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):  at
> org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLoader.loadFromAsset(TMXLoader.java:102)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> com.example.abc.TMXTiledMapExample.onCreateScene(TMXTiledMapExample.java:100)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity.onCreateScene(SimpleBaseGameActivity.java:48)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$3.onCreateResourcesFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:169)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity.onCreateResources(SimpleBaseGameActivity.java:43)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:181)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:110)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1348)
> 08-29 15:50:56.171: E/AndEngine(4495):    at
> android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

Even I tried to load the tmx file provided by examples it is giving the same error. Any idea where I am going wrong?

I am creating tmx file using Tiled Map Editor Vesion 0.8.1 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you fetch last version of AndEngine.
It seams that it has been fixed :

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension/pull/9

**Edit :** Hum, sorry, the pull request has not been submitted yet. You should try to apply it in your own git andengine repo.
Or as a simpled fix, you should change your tile Ids to values different than 0.

Comment: Yes it was a bug fix. I had to manually fix the bug in andengine code using the link you provided. Thanks...